# PHP: optimum configuration storage?

Tags: php, configuration, precompiling

My application gets configured via a lot of key/values (let's say 30.000 for instance)

I want to find the best deployment method for these configurations, knowing that I want to avoid DEFINEs to allow for runtime re-configuration.

I have thought of

- pre-compiling them into an array via a php file
- pre-compiling them into a tmpfs sqlite database
- pre-compiling them into a memcached db

what are my options for

- the best random access time to these configuration (memory is not an issue) ?
- the best structured access time if i can break up these configuration into families like (network, i18n, ..)

Thanks
Jerome

Comment: What is your application doing that it needs 30k settings?

Comment: there are different axis for growth : i18n keys, branding, seo urls

Comment: There's an issue I see here. On one hand, you say memory is not an issue. On the other hand, you say that you need high performance. While using a flat array is the fastest option, the irony is that it will be very slow if it's huge because it might be paged to disk unless you have infinite ram. I don't understand why you aren't using a database.

Comment: round-trip database access (the db is a remote db) would take several milliseconds for each config key. I agree with your paging issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if memory isn't an issue, just serialize an array to a file. There is absolutely no faster solution than this. You don't have the I/O and library overhead of SQLite, and you don't have the network overhead of memcached.

But keep in mind, memory must *really* not be an issue. You'd be loading the entire 30,000 element array into memory at once, as opposed to using a database, where you could load them on an as-needed basis.

To structure the settings, you could put each in its own file.

But really, you should be using a database. That's what they're there for. I really question why you would need to worry about 30k settings..you might want to reconsider your application design.

Comment: Random Access Memory always provides the best random access in my experience.

Comment: @webbiedave: can't argue with that statement.

Comment: by "serialize" an array to a file, you mean creating the array in a php file, or using the unserialize method on a pre-serialized array ? Does that make a performance difference ?

Comment: Just use `serialize()`. You're worrying too much about performance. Yeah, I guess you could generate a `.php` file that contains an array, but then you'd have to manually loop through your massive array and output each key/value. You'd have to check the datatype to make sure it's quoted and escaped properly. You'd have to handle nested arrays correctly. Or, you could just use `serialize()`. That's what it's there for.

Comment: And do you really need access to 30,000 settings at once?

Comment: no. but the access depends on what path the user request takes through the code.

Comment: Typically, how many settings do you need to load per request? Couldn't you just figure out what settings they need and load them all at once at the end of the request using an `IN` clause?

Answer (score 0):

How about in a database?

With a schema like this:

```
| key | value |
```

You could have data like this:

```
| currency | pound |
| timezone | GMT   |
```

It also means you can query it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM options WHERE key = 'timezone'
```

Or even return many options:

```
SELECT * FROM options WHERE key IN ('timezone','currency')
```

This can be in any kind of database, not least an SQLite database. If you're using a language such as PHP you can use [ADOdb](http://adodb.sourceforge.net) for database abstraction so your application is portable between different database types, just a thought if you were concerned about being tied down to one database.

Comment: The problem with a simple database setup is the access time. For each key or group of keys needed in a specific php code zone you need a request. Even with a cache that would probably mean hundreds of database fetch.

Comment: I don't know if I'm misunderstanding your point, but are you saying you would have repeating code? Because you can easily use functions or even classes as a wrapper and fetch the options that way, for instance `Options::getOption('timezone')`.

Comment: no. There is an in-process cache for already fetched keys, but depending on the page being rendered, the keys may be different

Answer (score 0):

If you want structured, I'd say ini files using the [parse_ini_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function.