# Environment dependent values

Tags: php

Sometimes I need to use a value that is dynamic in a way that it would be different depending on whether the code is executed on a testing environment or a remote host.

To address that I've been using the following function:

```
function localhost($local_host_value, $remote_host_value = "")
{
   if($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == "127.0.0.1")
   {
      return $local_host_value;
   }
   else
   {
      return $remote_host_value;
   }
}
```

Could you suggest a more elegant approach or at least a better name for the above quoted function?

Comment: Um... the code is always executed on local host :P

Comment: @Mchl, by local I meant a testing environment (127.0.0.1). What would be the proper term?

Comment: 'testing environment' would be the proper term ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this approach is not optimal in the long run, as all the settings are distributed all over your code, and it's very hard to e.g. add a third server environment (say, a live staging server).

I would consider using a central configuration of some sort that loads all configuration values at one point depending on which server it is running on.

Related:

- [What's Is the Best File Format for Configuration Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476892/whats-is-the-best-file-format-for-configuration-files)
- [PHP: optimum configuration storage ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623021/php-optimum-configuration-storage)

Answer (score 1):

you can try [`getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) if you dis-like using super-global variables

```
// Example use of getenv()
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

// Or simply use a Superglobal ($_SERVER or $_ENV)
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

as for the function name

```
function is_localhost(...)    <-- more like determine is local host (boolean)

function get_host_value(...)  <-- (string)
```

Comment: `is_localhost(...)` for me suggests that it will return a boolean wether we are in localhost or not... I find `get_value_for_host(...)` or `get_host_value(...)` more descriptive

Answer (score 1):

```
function localhost($local_host_value, $remote_host_value = '') {
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1'? $local_host_value : $remote_host_value;
}
```

Is more concise and clean in my opinion, but does just the same.
Or with getenv as ajreal suggests:

```
function localhost($local_host_value, $remote_host_value = '') {
    return getenv('REMOTE_ADDR') == '127.0.0.1'? $local_host_value : $remote_host_value;
}
```

About the function name, maybe `get_host_value(...)` would be my choice

PS: try to use single quotes instead of double quotes when your string does not contain variables: [Is there a performance benefit single quote vs double quote in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482202/is-there-a-performance-benefit-single-quote-vs-double-quote-in-php)